# How to embed h.264 video full width and responsive on webpage

Tags: wordpress, html, video, responsive-design, fullscreen

I have a video in h.264 codec and want it to be autoplayed in full width on my webpage. Til now I am using a html5 swiffy container with a swf in it and css wrapper to get a responsive animation on any devices:

CSS

```
.wrapper  {
max-height: initial !important;
    margin 0 !important; 
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="h_iframe">
         <img class="ratio" src="http://www.geronimo-film.de/wp-content/uploads/Imagefilm-Köln.jpg"/>
         <iframe src="http://www.geronimo-film.de/wp-content/flash/geronimo.html"></iframe>
    </div>
       </div>
```

The same thing I like to do with my video. 
Can you help me?

Comment: Perhaps necessary to know that I am using wordpress.

Comment: you should add wordpress to tags of the question

Answer (score 0):

Edit: During the discussion with the asker it showed that the video itself has a border. This approach crops the video and draws it to a canvas. This is based on the video of the asker - values can differ for different videos. Also keep in mind to edit the code if you change the source video size:

HTML:

```
<video controls autoplay loop id="video">
  <source src="http://www.geronimo-film.de/wp-content/flash/animation.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <p>Your browser does not support H.264/MP4.</p>
</video>

<div class="wrapper">
  <canvas id="cropCvs" width="1800" height="700></canvas>
</div>
```

JS (based on [this tutorial](https://developertip.wordpress.com/2011/06/04/tuto-html5-how-to-crop-a-video-tag-into-a-canvas-tag/)):

```
function loop() {
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  ctx.drawImage(video, 10, 195, 1800, 700, 0, 0, 1800, 700);
  setTimeout(loop, 1000 / 30);
}
var canvas = document.getElementById('cropCvs');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
loop();
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  margin 0 !important;
}

video {
  display: none;
}

#cropCvs {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w6g9ofkc/

---

This is working if the video has no rendered border:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <video controls autoplay loop>
    <source src="your_video_path.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <p>Your browser does not support H.264/MP4.</p>
  </video>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  margin 0 !important;
}

video{
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: fill; /*can also be contain depending on the input data*/
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xo7c2w9t/3

Comment: Thank you! That works. But now I have two black bars on top and bottom of the video. I know that they come from rendering the video. But is it possible to size it in a way they disappear?

Comment: Unfortunately the bars stay despite using object fit. And when I remove width: 100 % it won't be responsive any more.

Comment: And could you please add a command to loop the video? Sorry for I am rookie :)

Comment: It is as simple as the autoplay ;) just add `loop` as attribute. Do you set a height manually to the video (via CSS or as height attribute in video tag)? Which browser version are you using?

Comment: See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xo7c2w9t/4/ - it is working as expected (you can resize the preview part)

Comment: I tried it with object-fit: cover but it also did not work. In the video settings I just specified 1920x1080 px and in two other versions 1280x720 px and 640x480 px for mobile devices.

Comment: Did you check the fiddle in my last comment if this is working as you want to?

Comment: Yes, I did. It is full width and responsible. Only the black bars won't disappear. They are in the video but in the animation I was using before there were white bars and they disappeared after embeding the html5 on my webpage. Do you have another idea what could solve the problem?

Comment: What happens if you use `contain` instead of fill in your case? And what happens if you set `width="1280" height="720"` to your video tag?

Comment: Using contain in custom css and fixed width and height stays the same. Naturally it is not responsive.

Comment: I tried it now using elastic video code. It worked neither.

Comment: Does the video have the black borders in it?? what happens if you set `height: calc(100vw/1.777);`? Is your video online available?

Comment: Yes, they are. You can see the video here: http://www.geronimo-film.de/wp-content/flash/animation.mp4    I had another video in a size where there are no bars but there you see a video player border on the bottom.

Comment: That was what I expected - the black borders are inside the video, so they are of course included with the methods mentioned above. Can you render the video again without the borders? This would be easier than croping it ;-) (https://developertip.wordpress.com/2011/06/04/tuto-html5-how-to-crop-a-video-tag-into-a-canvas-tag/)

Comment: I'm trying it at the moment. The project-file is not on my computer so perhaps there is no other way than cropping it. Is it possible to crop it in a way it is responsive anyway?

Comment: Edited above...cropping is added.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience! There is only one problem left: When I add the comands you've posted above, the row below the video-sequence slips behind the video.

Comment: Set `display: block;` for canvas. Now the answer should be ready to confirm :D and think about reading some basic CSS tutorials.

Comment: I swear I'll do. :D Solved it now by putting an iframe around cause your hint to set display: block; did also not work for me. Then the vide was invisible.

Comment: Accepting the answer would be appreciated